# On Google Compute Engine, is it possible to have VMs from one project talk to VMs from another project over the internal network?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it possible for VMs from one project to talk to VMs from another project over the internal network?

I ask this because we've hit some quota limits and we could try to divide our VMs into groups in separate projects.

I tried connecting to ports in another project using the internal IP address but to no avail. It just hangs. When I do the same from another VM from the same project, it works.

$ telnet 10.240.91.247 7023
Trying 10.240.91.247...

I also don't see an obvious way in the firewall to open that up.

Comment: why cant you just flush/disable to firewall to see if tha tis the real issue ? If it is networking then you need to have a bridge connecting both interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to use their public IP addresses.  If you've hit quota limits, the best option is to actually request a [quota increase](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform).  There's a bit more quota information [here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas).